# Is there an idiomatic variable for the terminal executable in Linux?

Tags: linux, arch-linux, environment-variables, terminal-emulator

There's already [`EDITOR`, `BROWSER` and `VISUAL`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Environment_variables#Examples) which point to various executables (with or without full path). [`TERM` contains information about the *type* of terminal](https://linux.die.net/man/7/term), not necessarily the name of the executable (in `xterm` it's `xterm-color`, and in `gnome-terminal` it's `xterm-256color`). **Is there a variable which is expected to contain the name or path of the executable to use as the default terminal in Linux?** (Or Arch Linux, if there is a custom convention.) Maybe this is nonsensical, since GUI programs are rarely spawned from shells which know of these variables…

Comment: There is no such thing.  The closest I can think of are [xdg-utils](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/xdg-utils/), and, on _some_ incarnations of Linux, [alternatives](https://linux.die.net/man/8/alternatives).

Comment: @SatoKatsura Can you add that as an answer? Yours is the only one so far that addresses the actual question.

Comment: In xterm it's not "xterm-color" (an FAQ).

Comment: This StackOverflow question "[Determine the current user's shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16943685/determine-the-current-users-shell)" has some relevant info on how to get the login shell, which usually matches the preferred one.

Comment: @cafce25 Shell ≠ terminal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no standard environment variable used for setting a preferred terminal program.  The closest approximations seem to be [xdg-utils](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/xdg-utils/), and [alternatives](https://linux.die.net/man/8/alternatives).

The former provides a general mechanism for setting preferred applications for opening files based on their MIME types.  On Linux it's used by all major desktop environments.

The latter is available only on certain Linux distributions, and is a mechanism for setting preferred applications among several implementations performing the same functions.

Comment: Maybe also mention that the program name in `alternatives` is `x-terminal-emulator` (if my memory serves).